# How to access value in an object with dynamic key inhandleBars

Tags: handlebars.js

I have data like below:

```
"empIds" : { "43435352" : "[10, 27, 56, 13]", "56623222" : "[34, 56, 78, 16]" }
```

Where keys in above case are 43435352 , 56623222

My requirement is: i want to get the value when i pass the key.

For ex: when i pass key "43435352", it should give me [10, 27, 56, 13].

Could you please help me how to do this in HandleBars JS.

I tried various ways like below, but its not working

```
      {{#each empIds}}
           {{#withItem ../empIdskey=@key }} {{this}} {{/withItem}}
      {{/each}}

      Handlebars.registerHelper('withItem', function(object, options, ecrId){
            if(object[options.hash.key] == ecrId)
                return options.fn(object[options.hash.key]);
      });   
        Handlebars.registerHelper('lookup', function(obj, field) {
            return obj[field];
        });
```

NOTE: Key is dynamic, and we should be able to pass the key and get the value.

Could you please do the needful help?

Thank you

Comment: When you're using `{{#each}}` with that data structure, `{{this}}` will be already the value, eg. "[10, 27, 56, 13]".